# Generic class needs to access property in Where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I currently have a repository that inherits from the base class BaseRepository, as below. When an instrument is needed by its Type, this works fine. However, I don't want to define GetByType in the derived class, but in BaseRepository instead. Obviously, the non-abstract method in BaseRepository won't work, because it knows nothing explicit what is in TEntity. I.e, it doesn' know what i.Type is. How do I implement this?

```
public class InstrumentRepository : BaseRepository<Instrument>
{
    // overrides the ABSTRACT method in the base class 
    public override IEnumerable<Instrument> GetByType(string type)
    {
        return db.Instruments.Where(i => i.Type == type); 
    }
}

abstract public class BaseRepository<TEntity>
{
    publicMyDbContext db;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public BaseRepository()
    {
        db = new MyDbContext();

        // create a DBSet from the given TEntity           
        this.dbSet = db.Set<TEntity>(); 
    }

    // what I have now
    abstract public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetByType(string type); 

    // I want something like this instead, and I would get rid 
    // of the abstract method.
    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetByType(string type)
    {
        // of course this doesn't compile
        return dbSet.Where(i => i.Type == type); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you not put the 'Type' property in your base class? Assuming other child classes use it too

Comment: What is wrong with `.OfType<T>()` ? This extension method is defined on both `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: Or `Object#GetType()` and comparing types instead of strings.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten `Type` is a property of the object in question, h'es not actually filtering based on the C# type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to define an interface for your `TEntity` that provides a Type method.

```
public interface IEntity 
{
     string Type {get;}
}
```

You can then constrain your base class generic parameter to this, which will allow your existing code to compile (as the compiler will know that any `TEntity` will have a `Type` property available).

```
abstract public class BaseRepository<TEntity>
     where TEntity: IEntity
{
```

You must also ensure that `Instrument` (and any other repository types you implement) implements `IEntity`:

```
public class Instrument : IEntity 
{
    public string Type 
    {
         get { return "Instrument" }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's it. As a side note, I also had to add a class constraint, as DbSet requires a reference type. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I made a little helper to do something similar which might be of use to you.

Essentially you use it to create a predicate from a property name and a value.

```
public static Func<TEntity, bool> MakeFilter<TEntity>(string _propertyName, object _value) where TEntity : class
    {
        var type = typeof(TEntity);

        var property = type.GetProperty(_propertyName);

        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
        var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
        var constantValue = Expression.Constant(_value);

        var equality = Expression.Equal(propertyAccess, constantValue);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(equality, parameter).Compile();
    }
```

Usage like: `array.FirstOrDefault(LinqHelper.MakeFilter<YourType>(itemName,valueToLookFor));`